# spring batch : Running/stopping multiple instances of job

Tags: spring, spring-batch

i m a newbie with spring batch.
i must develop a job that read from database and write on flat file.
many users can launch my job from a web application developped by spring mvc. the client want that it be in parallel, also he want to give to the user the possibility for stopping a job (instance of job).
it s possibld with spring batch ?
if yes can you give me an exmples espicially for stopping an instance of job ?
thanks

Comment: Hope this will be help ful - http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/64297-starting-or-stopping-spring-batch-jobs-programmatically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948605/spring-batch-executing-multiple-instances-of-a-job-at-same-time